# Unable to locate folder created by android app from pc

Tags: java, android, file

I have created a small folder by using this code:

```
public void createFile(View view) throws IOException {
        File file=new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"MyApp");
        Log.d(tag,file.exists()+"");
        Log.d(tag,file.mkdir()+"");
    }
```

I'm creating this folder to read some csv files that are placed by user.

The problem is that I'm able to see the folder from my mobile but not when on my PC when the mobile is connected.

I've made sure that I changed mode from charging only to file transfer.

Comment: Put some files in that folder and reboot your device.

Comment: Thanks a lot man...If you have't said this I would have left my project...Really thanks a lot bro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who face similar problem here is the solution.The folders created are visible only when they contain some files (which we have to place manually and not created by program). Then they are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Connect mobile to your PC and try `adb shell sync`